# Phonegap + jQuery mobile: injecting html files from iOS app's Documents folder with jQuery Mobile

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an app which uses both Phonegap and JQuery Mobile.
The app connects to an external server to check for new content/content updates (html and pdf files).
If needed, in iOS those files are successfully downloaded into the app /Documents folder.
The app then retrieves each content file's absolute path (*file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/APPID/Documents/subfolder*) and creates listviews that link to each file's absolute path.

The problem I am having is the following: ***tapping a listview opens the linked page BUT not as an ajax call. The page loads but then no javascript (cordova.js, jquery.js app.js etc) is referenced in the page and hence I can't navigate back to the main menu. It seems like the jQueryMobile ajax navigation stops working when I open html files in the /Documents folder.
This happens only for the downloaded content in the /Documents folder (and hence outside Phonegap's www folder).***

From the remote debugger, if I try to call the `$.mobile.changePage('previousPage.html')*` function, the console returns that $ is not defined, as if the page couldn't reference jQuery. But in none of the pages in the /www folder I need to re-reference the js files.

The app uses a multipage layout and each page has its own javascript after the `<div data-role="page" id="pageid">` container. 
Each .html in the /Documents folder is structured as a jQueryMobile page (with data-role attributes).

This is the code that creates the listviews:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#content').live('pagebeforeshow', function(e) {
                            var curCat = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('currentCat'));

                            console.log('PAGE BEFORE SHOW: CONTENT');
                            db.db.transaction(function(tx) {
                                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `content`.`catID` = ?', [curCat],
                                    function(tx, result) {
                                        var path = window.localStorage.getItem('contentPath') + '/';
                                        if (result.rows && result.rows.length) {
                                            var html = '<ul data-role="listview" id="linkUl">';
                                            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                                                var filename = result.rows.item(i).index_file.substr(result.rows.item(i).index_file.lastIndexOf('/'));
                                                console.log(result.rows.item(i).id);
                                                html += '<li id="' + result.rows.item(i).id + '">';
                                                html += '<a href="' + path + filename +'">';
                                                html += result.rows.item(i).title;
                                                html += '</a></li>';
                                            }
                                            html += '</ul>';
                                            console.log(html);
                                            $('#contCnt').html(html);
                                            $('ul#linkUl').listview();
                                        }

                                    },
                                    function(tx, error) {
                                        console.log(error.code);
                                        var html = '<div id="errorDB">';
                                            html += 'ERROR RETRIEVING FILES';
                                            html += '</div>';
                                        $('#contCnt').html(html);
                                    }
                                );
                            });
                        });
                        $('div#content').live('pageshow', function(e) {
                            $('ul#linkUl').listview('refresh');
                        });

</script>
```

where the ContentPath variable is stored as a fileSystem object's directory.toUrl();

My fear is that jQueryMobile can't ajax-pull html from an external directory (the /Documents folder in iOS), or that I am missing some attribute or setting in order to do so.
Perhaps because I am using an absolute url? If so, how can I get the relative url from Phonegap's /www folder?
Do I have to declare something on the cordova.plist file?

Also, the downloaded content won't have to contain any js, they should be only plain html, but I need to keep jQuery Mobile header/footer and navigation system in all the pages.

I am using Cordova 2.2.0 and the latest releases of both jQuery and jQuery mobile.

Thanks in advance and sorry if something in the formatting goes wrong, I am new to SO (in case I'll edit asap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, and thanks to Tom who led me through the right direction.

I guess the problem was that jQueryMobile was interpreting the absolute path as a an external link and thus the WebView was opening the html files as a new file, detaching it from the rest of the application.

What I did was substituting the absolute path `file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/APPID/Documents/subfolder`

with a relative one, which in my case is `'./../../Documents/subfolder/filename.html`

and now it works like a charm.

Comment: you are my hero.  Why an absolute path doesn't work here gets an extra big WTF from yours truly.

Answer (score 2):

You can open files from the documents folder (or any other folder the app has read access to).

There are two reasons that a link may not load as an ajax page

1. jQuery Mobile thinks that it isn't part of the app
2. There is a javascript error loading the page, which causes the default link click action to run instead of the ajax loader.

You could try using a call to $.mobile.changePage instead of just setting up the links - that gives you a little bit more visibility into what is going on.

I don't think a file url in a different folder should be treated as a different domain by jQuery Mobile, but to eliminate that possibility it should be reasonably easy to construct a relative url to the documents folder.